# My question was closed but now I have edited it

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, re-open

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Hard permutation question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4863294/hard-permutation-question)

My question was closed and I did not get an option to send it for review even though I have edited it now. Please help me. I have edited it, please reopen it.

Comment: Your "question" never actually states a question. Also, you refer to your answer and your solution, but you give no idea of how you solved the problem (whatever that problem might be).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Question was submitted for Reopen review as a result of your editing.  It's a good idea to prepare all the revisions for submission at one time to take best advantage of this feature.

My impression is that you are passing along an assignment with some ambiguity about which seatings are counted as being the same.  You might have to take up the proper interpretation of the exercise with your instructor before turning to Math.SE for help.

Comment: Ok I will keep this in mind